# The argument of foo has an extra }.

Tags: errors, amsmath, align, expansion

I'm trying to write a command that does, effectively, an `\fbox` in something like an `align` environment.  The following code works:

```
\usepackage{etextools}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\alignedfbox}[1]{\@aligedfbox{#1}{}#1&\@endalignedfbox}
\def\@aligedfbox#1#2#3&#4\@endalignedfbox{%
  \ifempty{#4}{%
    \vrule
    \edef\temp{\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\@@aligedfbox{#2#3}#1&\@@endalignedfbox}}%
    \temp
  }{%
    \edef\temp{\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\@aligedfbox{#1}{#2#3}#4\@endalignedfbox}}%
    \temp
  }%
}
\def\@@aligedfbox#1#2&#3\@@endalignedfbox{%
  \underline{\overline{{}#2\vphantom{#1}}}
  \ifempty{#3}{%
    \vrule
  }{%
    &
    \edef\temp{\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\@@aligedfbox{#1}#3\@@endalignedfbox}}%
    \temp
  }%
}
```

and then

```
\begin{align*}
  \alignedfbox{1 & = 2}
\end{align*}
```

However, the `\edef\temp{\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{...}}\temp` sequence is very ugly, and I'm not sure why I need it.  (But if I replace it with `...`, it fails with the error mentioned in the title of this post, that my arguments to `\@alignedfbox`/`\@@alignedfbox` have an extra }.  Surprisingly, this error does not occur when I call `\@aligedfbox{#1}{}#1&\@endalignedfbox}` from `\alignedfbox`.)  I think it has something to do that `align` and friends gather everything inside the environment into a macro before execution, and something to do with `\protect`/`\protected` and how TeX's behavior in expansion-only contexts is different from its behavior in other contexts, but I'm not sure.

What's a replacement for `\edef\temp{\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{...}}\temp`, and what's an explanation for why `...` doesn't work by itself, in this instance?

Comment: I discovered that I can change the `\edef\temp{\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{...}}\temp` in `\@@aligedfbox` to `\expandafter\relax...`.  I have no idea why this is the case, nor why I can't do the same in `\@aligedfbox`.

Comment: Have you tried the \Aboxed command from the `mathtools` package, it does something similar, but less complicated

Comment: The `\Aboxed` command from `mathtools` works.  Thanks!  But it doesn't answer my request for an explanation of why I'm getting those errors.

Comment: sorry, no time to investigate

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am in a similar situation where your weird `\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter` workaround gets rid of one error in favor of another error.

Answer (score 5):

As already suggested, you shouldn't reenvent the wheel ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \Aboxed{1 &= 2 }\\
  1 &\ne 2
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually there is apparently an error in it (I wrote it ;-(, try `\Aboxed{\int_4 &= 2 }`

Comment: Always the same old story ... `\protect\int...`

Comment: not really, I used `$\displaystyle#1{}$`, that `{}` is irrelevant

Comment: I do not understand anything what you are talking about

Comment: Likewise, what should `\protect\int` help? See my answer above, there the internal of `\Aboxed` is fixed

Answer (score 3):

This seems better (will be fixed in the next mathtools)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\makeatletter
\def\@Aboxed#1&#2\ENDDNE{%
 \settowidth\@tempdima{$\displaystyle#1$}% <-
 \addtolength\@tempdima{\fboxsep}%
 \addtolength\@tempdima{\fboxrule}%
 \global\@tempdima=\@tempdima
 \kern\@tempdima
 &
 \kern-\@tempdima
\boxed{#1#2}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \Aboxed{1 &= 2 }\\
  1 &\ne 2
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```